# React.js - How can I call a component's method easily from anywhere?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a data processing application that frequently updates the user with [toasts](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/toasts/) so I have set up a `<ToastContainer />` component that contains a method `doToast(title, time, content){...}` and it works nicely to spawn a toast on screen that autohides after some duration.

```
export default class ToastContainer extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      toastList: [],
    }

    this.pushToast = this.pushToast.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      
      <div id="toast-container" className="toast-container position-absolute top-0 end-0 p-3" style={{'zIndex': 999}}>

        {this.state.toastList.map(toast => (

          <Toast ... />

        ))}

      </div>
    )
  }

  pushToast(title, time, content)
  {

    var newToast = {
      title: title,
      time: time,
      content: content,
    }

    this.setState({
      toastList: [...this.state.toastList, newToast]
    })
  }

}
```

All throughout my application I have components that make AJAX calls to my backend, and I'd like to be able to easily notify the user of what happened during/after the call with a toast (i.e. success, warning, failure, etc).

The only way I know to call methods from another component is to pass that method as a prop to the child component. I don't want to have to have to pass the `doToast` method down to the long chain of components every time I want to call a toast -- is there a way to 'globally' call `doToast()` so I can use it willy-nilly?

Comment: Maybe look into the `Context` api? https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: I think you can have `useReducer` which will expose functions to add any new toasts via context. Your `ToastContainer` can read state from context and then render. Will make it really loosely coupled.

Comment: I have done something similar using functional components - https://replit.com/@jaybhatt21/Create-React-App.

It might ask you to create account, sorry for that.